# Kernel 3.18 CMA: dma_alloc_coherent fails

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I tried to use the Contiguous Memory Allocater (CMA) feature and I passed cma=1G to the kernel (3.18) as boot parameter, but I haven't managed to get it work. I try to allocate large chunks of contiguous memory in a device driver (200-500MB), but allocation with dma_alloc_coherent always fails for data sizes larger than 4MB.

I did some research on that and some suggests to disable SWIOTLB, but this didn't help. Also, I took a look into the kernel sources and I'm actually not sure if CMA is really implemented for the main branch of the kernel? I couldn't find a satisfying answer to this as well.

Does anybody know more about this? Is CMA expected to work? If so, what could be a possible issue with dma_alloc_coherent? It just returns NULL and I do not get any more information out of it.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: This question sounds better suited for the [LKML](https://lkml.org/). Especially considering it's about a very recent release of the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I also tried it with Kernel 3.13, didn't work either. I think it's more of a general question about CMA and its implementation in the main development branch. There are some articles at LKML about it, but as I said, it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The dma_alloc_coherent() always allocate the lower 4G memory, please try to specify the cma start address and size by cma=@, how the start-address is determined is according to the memory map table when the kernel started. You saw this issue, because your system is 64bit.